Исчезают метки - PlaceMarks и полигоны при zoom yandex карты
[введите сюда описание ссылки][1]при zoom Yandex карты исчезают метки и полигоны, геообъекты. Не исчезают совсем а перерисовываются будто. Как можно решить проблему? Карту подключаю стандартно с стандартными опциями. codepen.io/volos11223344/pen/dyLVOZa, здесь пример - например после клика на показать полигоны(кнопку) они отрисовываются, но при zoom пропадают на секунды, так же и placeMark
  [1]: https://codepen.io/volos11223344/pen/dyLVOZa


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Пожалуйста, соберите минимальный рабочий пример кода здесь или в любой другой удобной вам песочнице, например jsbin.com, чтобы была возможность увидеть вашу проблему живьём и оценить возможные причины.

Извиняюсь за картинку, https://codepen.io/volos11223344/pen/dyLVOZa, здесь пример - например после клика на показать полигоны(кнопку) они отрисовываются, но при zoom пропадают на секунды, так же и placeMark

Вы используете версию API 2.0 – это версия устарела. Достаточно изменить версию API на 2.1 – и масштабирование начинает работать плавно даже без перестройки кода.

Большое спасибо, да стало работать отлично, благодарю
